# Additional field on preview

Tags: dropzone

I am using Dropzonejs to upload images. Once the images are uploaded they have to be approved.  When approved I update the approved_ind for the files.

On the initial load, I display files and would like to include this approved_ind with the file name and size.

How do I access this additional field from the file object in the preview template?